# How can I add programmatically add a PushPin, and could I make it have a custom image?

Tags: c#, maps, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a map application but the examples I find describes a `myMap.Children` list that my `myMap` object does not have :-(

I've created a map, pretty much straight forward:

```
<maps:Map Visibility="Collapsed" Name="MyMap" Height="670" Width="400" ZoomLevel="10" Pitch="0" CartographicMode="Hybrid" Margin="30,0" />
```

So how can I in C# add PushPins, and could these have a image from `Assets`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Nokia's Maps tutorial on "[Adding Graphics to a Map control](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!guide-to-the-maps.html;#toc_Addinggraphicstoamapcontrol)" or see MSDN's "[How to add UIElements to a Map control in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207037%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)".

It's mostly around adding you own MapLayer with multiple MapOverlay on top of it:

```
private void DrawMapMarkers()
{
    MyMap.Layers.Clear();
    MapLayer mapLayer = new MapLayer();

    // Draw marker for current position
    if (MyCoordinate != null)
    {
        DrawAccuracyRadius(mapLayer);
        DrawMapMarker(MyCoordinate, Colors.Red, mapLayer);
    }

    ...

    MyMap.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
}

private void DrawMapMarker(GeoCoordinate coordinate, Color color, MapLayer mapLayer)
{
    // Create a map marker
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 75));
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(25, 0));
    polygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);

    // Enable marker to be tapped for location information
    polygon.Tag = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
    polygon.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Marker_Click);

    // Create a MapOverlay and add marker
    MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
    overlay.Content = polygon;
    overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
    overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
    mapLayer.Add(overlay);
}
```

In order to databind the new WP8 Nokia Map control, use MapExtensions from the new [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com). For example here's [how to create a PushPin in a specific GeoCoordinate](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336302) using MapExtensions.

```
<maps:Map x:Name="Map" Grid.Row="1" Hold="OnMapHold">
    <maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
        <maptk:Pushpin x:Name="RouteDirectionsPushPin" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <maptk:MapItemsControl Name="StoresMapItemsControl">
            <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maptk:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding GeoCoordinate}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" Content="{Binding Address}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </maptk:MapItemsControl>
        <maptk:UserLocationMarker x:Name="UserLocationMarker" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
</maps:Map>
```