# Add more than one coordination to windows phone 8 map

Tags: windows-phone-8

My wp8 app has different coordinations loaded from xml and all coordinations should be shown in a map? Every thing in my app is created dynamically, so I progrmatically creat the map and add maplayer and mapoverlay. But it seems i can not add more than one mapoverlay to maplayer. Please help me.

```
MapOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                myLocationOverlay.Content = pinIMG;
                myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                myLocationOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(57.724611, 12.938945);

MapOverlay myLocationOverlay2 = new MapOverlay();
                myLocationOverlay2.Content = pinIMG;
                myLocationOverlay2.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                myLocationOverlay2.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(57.724155, 12.939023);

MapLayer myLocationLayer = new MapLayer();
myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay);
myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay2);
MyMap.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer);
```

It works good with one mapoverlay but not two.

Comment: Please add more information to your question and post some code of what you are currently doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add programmatically add a PushPin, and could I make it have a custom image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267149/how-can-i-add-programmatically-add-a-pushpin-and-could-i-make-it-have-a-custom)

Comment: You can't add the same Image to the Content of the MapOverlay... not sure why, you just can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From playing around with your example, I found that assiging the same `Image` object to the `MapOverlays`' content variable does not work (debugging exception is thrown). Giving the `MapOverlays` a unique `Image` object was the solution:

Assuming you are using bitmap images, then this is sufficient:

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/pinIMG.png", UriKind.Relative));

System.Windows.Controls.Image pinIMG1 = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
pinIMG1.Source = bmp;

System.Windows.Controls.Image pinIMG2 = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
pinIMG2.Source = bmp;

// MapOverlay and MapLayer setup (each overlay gets its on pinIMG...)
```

It sounds like you might be using a loop to generate `MapOverlays` when loading coordinates from XML. If this is the case, just setup a new image each time through the loop rather than reusing the same instance across each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer in another thread on this question @ [How can I add programmatically add a PushPin, and could I make it have a custom image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267149/how-can-i-add-programmatically-add-a-pushpin-and-could-i-make-it-have-a-custom/14269412#14269412)

Short version is that you can either programmatically generate multiple MapOverlays in a single MaPlayer, or you can use MapExtensions pushpin databinding to do that for you.

Also, there's a bug in your code. You can't add the same UIElement (in this case Image) to the visual tree twice. AS user8709 said, you should create a new UIElement for each MapOverlay.