# windows phone 8 maps and pushpins

Tags: c#, google-maps, xaml, windows-phone-8, pushpin

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8. I am new to it. I am using google maps. I add a pushpin on the map but I don't know how to move the pushpin from one location to another after the co-ordinates of the pushpin has been once saved. Can I make a box of button controls where we can choose from moving, deleting or editing title of the pushpin?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using Google Maps APIs on WP8? The built-in Maps control is much better and more responsive. Here's a previous answer of mine showing how to add pushpin to the WP8 Map control either directly via MapOverlay or via the Windows Phone Toolkit Map DataBinding extensions @ [How can I add programmatically add a PushPin, and could I make it have a custom image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267149/how-can-i-add-programmatically-add-a-pushpin-and-could-i-make-it-have-a-custom/14269412#14269412)

Comment: I am not using the Google Maps API. I have just changed the tile source of my map, thus giving the map output on google maps. This is done to achieve more details on the map for a particular location.
I can add a pushpin on the map. Thanks for your reply but I need to know how can i move a pushpin if say i tagged in the wrong location?